# Sobre Orientado a Objeto em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli

Eu tenho meu arquivo **conexao.php** com o código abaixo:

```
$banco_hostname = "localhost";
$banco_usuario="root";
$banco_passwd="";
$banco_nome="banquinho";
$conexao = new mysqli($banco_hostname,$banco_usuario,$banco_passwd,$banco_nome);
```

Ai no meu arquivo **banco.oo.php** com as classes (orientado a objeto) eu tenho:

```
class autenticacao {
    function SignUp($conexao,$nome_post,$email_post,$passwd_post,$k_post,$k) {
        if( (!$nome_post) || (!$email_post) || (!$passwd_post) || (!$k_post) || ($k_post != $k) ){
            header('location:index.php');
        }
        else{
                // VERIFICA SE USUARIO OU EMAIL EXISTE CADASTRADO
                $sql = $conexao->query("SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email_post'");
                if ($sql->num_rows==1){
                    echo '<div class="alertaIndexMSG">Ocorreu um erro, este e-mail ja possui um cadastro no banco de dados...</div>';
                }
                else {
                    $acessos=1;
                    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                    // INSERE USUARIO AO BANCO DE DADOS
                    $sql = $conexao->prepare("INSERT usuarios SET nome = ?, email = ?, passwd = ?, ip = ?, acessos = ?");
                    $sql->bind_param('ssssi',$nome_post,$email_post,$passwd_post,$ip,$acessos);
                    $sql->execute();
                    $_SESSION["message-signup"]=TRUE;
                    $_SESSION["autenticado"]=$email_post;
                    $_SESSION["usuario"]=$nome_post;
                    header('location:index.php');
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Ai no meu arquivo **index.php** eu teria um formulário para o SignUp como exemplo

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- FORMULARIO DE SIGN UP AQUI -->
</body>
</html>
```

Ai no meu arquivo que **processa o formulário de SignUp** eu tenho:

```
include("conexao.php");
include("banco.oo.php");
if (isset($_POST["signin"])){
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $passwd=md5($_POST["passwd"]);
    $OO = new autenticacao();
    $OO -> SignIn($conexao,$email,$passwd);
}
```

*Vamos então a minha dúvida/problema:*

Eu lembro que **antes eu não precisava levar a variavel $conexao sempre em todo $OO -> SignIn($conexao,$email,$passwd);** pois a mesma já estava puxando dentro do arquivo banco.oo.php quando inicia a classe acho que como herança da classe todas funções dela acabavam recebendo essa variavel que faz se conectar ao banco quando chama a classe, mas agora nao sei o que fiz errado no banco.oo.php que toda vez que chamo uma função tenho que sair levando essa variavel e recebendo ela lá na função pra se conectar ao banco.

Qual meu erro na orientação a objeto que fiz?

Comment: Não tem OOP nesse código. Separar em classes não significa OO - além do mais, você terá problemas em passar `$conexao`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode passar a conexão apenas uma vez, na instanciação da classe, e guardá-la numa propriedade. Algo assim:

```
// Nomes de classe costumam ter iniciais maiúsculas
class Autenticacao {

    // Propriedade
    private $conexao;

    // Construtor
    function Autenticacao($conexao) {
        $this->conexao = $conexao;
    }

    // Exemplo de uso em um método qualquer
    function dados($sql) {
        return $this->conexao->query($sql);
    }
}

// Instanciação e uso
$auth = new Autenticacao($conexao);
$auth->dados("SELECT 1");
```

Comment: Obrigado bfavaretto é exatamente isso que eu precisava, agora me lembrei, quando eu chegar em casa vou etntar fazer e dou um retorno aqui no tópico

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Métodos de classe estão sujeitos às restrições de escopo tal como funções. Para que um recurso no escopo global, externo, funcione no escopo local, do método, você tem que globalizar a variável (**não** faça isso!) ou injetar por meio de um parâqmetro.

---

Não vou entrar no mérito de que o que você tem codificado não tem nada a a ver com Orientação a Objetos, então, me atendo unicamente ao problema que você demonstrou, sugiro a você ler sobre [Escopo de Variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php).

Métodos de uma classe são funções, não adianta ninguém tentar argumentar. E se são funções, estão sujeitos às "limitações" (entre aspas pois não e uma limitação de fato) de escopo, local e global.

Muito provavelmente "antes funcionava" por não haver uma classe envolvida ou de alguma forma você localizava (não no sentido de encontrar) o escopo da variável **$conexao**.

Você quase fez certo ao injetar a instância da conexão na classe ao invés de usar a palavra-chave **global** ou o array superglobal **$GLOBALS**. Você errou quanto ao onde que, ao invés de ter sido no método, deveria ter sido no construtor da classe, atribuindo à uma propriedade, assim este ficaria disponível para todos os métodos da classe sem a necessidade de injetar toda hora, em cada método.

Comment: Humm vou analisar isso que voce me falou