# Erro no código classe function conexão

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com problema, veja o código que fiz:

```
<?php
class banco {
   public function __construct() {
 
        $banco_hostremoto = "127.0.0.1";
        $banco_hostname = "localhost";
        $banco_usuario="root";
        $banco_passwd="";
        $banco_nome="flptrevisan";
       
        $conn = mysql_connect($banco_hostname,$banco_usuario,$banco_passwd);
        if (!mysql_ping($conn)) {   $FORADOAR = TRUE;   }
        else if (mysql_ping($conn)) {
            $FORADOAR = FALSE;
            $conexao = new mysqli($banco_hostname,$banco_usuario,$banco_passwd,$banco_nome);
        }
       
    }
    public function signIn($email,$senha) {
        $this->conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'");
        if ($sql->num_rows==1){
                while($linha =  $sql->fetch_array()) {
                        $usuario = $linha['nome'];
                        $acessos = $linha['acessos']+1;
                }
                $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                $sql = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET acessos = ?, ip = ? WHERE email = ?");
                $sql->bind_param('iss',$acessos,$ip,$email);
                $sql->execute();
                $_SESSION["autenticado"]=$email;
                $_SESSION["usuario"]=$usuario;
                header('location:index.php');
        }
        else {
                echo '<div class="alertaIndexMSG">O usuário ou senha inserido é inválido(a)</div>';
        }
    }
 
}
```

Da o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined property: banco::$conexao in
> C:\htdocs\NetBeansProjects\flptrevisan\classes\conexao.class.php on
> line 20
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
> C:\htdocs\NetBeansProjects\flptrevisan\classes\conexao.class.php on
> line 20

Linha 20 é:

$this->conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'");

Answer (score 1):

Propriedades devem ser declaradas no corpo da classe no caso `$conexao` foi definida como uma variável local do construtor então logo após sua chamada ela perdera seu valor.

Defina `$conexao` como membro da classe assim:

```
class banco {
   private $conexao;
//........
```

Siga as orientações da [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27211/sobre-orientado-a-objeto-em-php)

Só reforçando algumas coisas:

- Evite receber/manipular super globais como $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION diretamente em métodos se precisar passas elas como parâmetro ou reatribua o valor como retorno(no caso fora da classe/método).
- Métodos devem fazer/resolver apenas uma parte do trabalho/problema, seu construtor está fazendo duas coias além de inicializar as variáveis está verificando se o servidor está online, se realmente precisar disso crie um novo método:

Mude:

```
public function __construct() {
    $conn = mysql_connect($banco_hostname,$banco_usuario,$banco_passwd);
    if (!mysql_ping($conn)) {
        $FORADOAR = TRUE;
    }else if (mysql_ping($conn)){
        $FORADOAR = FALSE;
        $conexao = new  mysqli($banco_hostname,$banco_usuario,$banco_passwd,$banco_nome);
    }
```

para:

```
public function servidorOnLine(){
  return $this->conexao->ping();
}
```

- Tem um mysql_* perdido ali no construtor esqueça ele, [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Olá, fiz a alteração mas continua dando erro:

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\htdocs\NetBeansProjects\flptrevisan\classes\conexao.class.php on line 13

Linha 13:

        $this->conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'"); 



Novo código completo:
http://pastebin.com/uJjR2WEK

Comment: Lembre de fazer a atribuição corretamente, aqui vc está adicionando a uma variável local `$conexao = new mysqli(...)` mude para: `$this->conexao = new mysqli(...)`

Comment: Deu, passou por aquele erro mas agora vem este: 
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\htdocs\NetBeansProjects\flptrevisan\classes\conexao.class.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\htdocs\NetBeansProjects\flptrevisan\classes\conexao.class.php on line 14
O usuário ou senha inserido é inválido(a)

Comment: O retorno da consulta(`$this->conexao->query()`) precisa ser atribuido a uma variável no caso `$sql`.

Comment: Obrigado agora esta dando certo

Comment: Agora eu estou ajustando o código na estrutura que quero e voltou a dar erro. Olha só, sao dois arquivos um com cada classe., a classe da conexao e a classe da autenticacao, eu quero herdar na autenticacao o construct da abertura da conexao.
Arquivo da classe autenticacao: http://pastebin.com/a7mfxSjU
Arquivo da classe da conexao: http://pastebin.com/FmfCWDRC

O erro é: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\htdocs\NetBeansProjects\flptrevisan\classes\autenticacao.class.php on line 8

Sempre naquela linha que chama o conexao

Comment: Consegui tirando o private da conexao para public!